# Batch file code - runs of CMD but not in .bat file

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd

I'm not very good at it and not familiar with syntax, I googled and I still cannot work out:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/" %d in ("%date%") do set curDate = _%d_%e 

"C:\WEBServer\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" --host="localhost" --user="root" --password=pass db > C:\WEBServer\MySQL\backup\db_%curDate%.sql

echo Done!
```

says:

```
C:\WEBServer>mySql.backup.bat
dated_e was unexpected at this time.
```

but the same code in CMD

```
C:\WEBServer>for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/" %d in ("%date%") do set curDate = _%d_%e
C:\WEBServer>set curDate = _17_05
```

all I need is to create a mysql dump file with current month and date, no year in the name....

please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/" %%d in ("%date%") do set "curDate=_%%d_%%e"
"C:\WEBServer\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" --host="localhost" --user="root" --password=pass db > C:\WEBServer\MySQL\backup\db_%curDate%.sql
echo Done!
```

In a batch file you need double `%%` for for loop variables.

Comment: it worked! but i did try with double % before... not sure what i did wrong... and thanks for fixing `"curDate=_%%d_%%e"`